# Function parameters evaluation in Scala (functional programming)

Tags: scala, functional-programming, evaluation

please find below a piece of code from Coursera online course (lecture 2.3) on functional programming in Scala.

```
package week2
import math.abs

object lecture2_3_next {
  def fixedPoint(f: Double => Double)(firstGuess: Double): Double = {
    val tolerance = 0.0001
    def isCloseEnough(x: Double, y: Double): Boolean = abs((x - y) / x) / x < tolerance
    def iterate(guess: Double): Double = {
      val next = f(guess)
      if (isCloseEnough(guess, next)) next
      else iterate(next)
    }
    iterate(firstGuess)
  }                                              

  def averageDamp(f: Double => Double)(x: Double): Double = (x + f(x)) / 2

  def sqrt(x: Double): Double = fixedPoint(averageDamp(y => x / y))(1)

  sqrt(2)                                         

}
```

A few points blocked me while I'm trying to understand this piece of code.

I'd like your help to understanding this code.

The 2 points that annoying me are :
- when you call averageDamp, there are 2 parameters 'x' and 'y' in the function passed (eg. `averageDamp(y => x / y)`) but you never specify the 'y' parameter in the definition of the averageDamp function (eg. `def averageDamp(f: Double => Double)(x: Double): Double = (x + f(x)) / 2`). Where and how do the scala compiler evaluate the 'y' parameter.
- second point may be related to the first, I don't know in fact. When I call the averageDamp function, I pass only the function 'f' parameter (eg. `y => x / y`) but I don't pass the second parameter of the function which is 'x' (eg. `(x: Double)` second parameter). How the scala compiler is evaluating the 'x' parameter in this case to render the result of the averageDamp call.

I think I missed something about the evaluation or substitution model of scala and functional programming.

Thank's for your help and happy new year !

Hervé

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You don't pass an `x` and an `y` parameter as `f`, you pass a function. The function is defined as `y => x / y`, where `y` is just a placeholder for the argument of this function, while `x` is a fixed value in this context, as it is given as argument for the `sqrt` method (in the example `x` is 2). Instead of the fancy lambda-syntax, you could write as well

```
def sqrt(x: Double): Double = fixedPoint(averageDamp(
    new Function1[Double,Double] {
       def apply(y:Double):Double = x / y
    }
))(1)
```

Nothing magic about this, just an abbreviation.

2) When you have a second parameter list, and don't use it when calling the method, you do something called "currying", and you get back a partial function. Consider

```
def add(x:Int)(y:Int) = x + y
```

If you call it as `add(2)(3)`, everything is "normal", and you get back 5. But if you call `add(2)`, the second argument is still "missing", and you get back a function expecting this missing second argument, so you have something like `y => 2 + y`

Comment: ok, thanks, I think this makes me my mind clear. If I reformulate your answer with the help of Gregor Rayman. I would say that my function averageDamp is passed to the calling function fixedPoint and it is used by the line `val next= f(guess)`. guess is the 'y' parameter I was looking for in the `y => x/y`and the x is the parameter passed to the sqrt function.

Answer (score 2):

The `x` is not a parameter of the (anonymous) function, it is a parameter of the function `sqrt`. For the anonymous function it is a bound closure.

To make it more obvious, let's rewrite it and use a named instead of an anonymous function:

```
def sqrt(x: Double): Double = fixedPoint(averageDamp(y => x / y))(1)
```

will can be rewritten as this:

```
def sqrt(x: Double): Double = {
   def funcForSqrt(y: Double) : Double = x / y  // Note that x is not a parameter of funcForSqrt

   // Use the function fundForSqrt as a parameter of averageDamp
   fixedPoint(averageDamp(funcForSqrt))(1) 
}
```